# How do I run my Orchard Module?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms

I have an almost standalone Orchard module. It is an app comprising a collection of controllers and views, and in performs it's own EF based data access.

Once I have installed and activated this module in Orchard, how do I request it's controller actions and be served it's views in response? I understand it must have a `Routes` class and suspect it is something here that I must do to enable access to my module. I know a module is actually an Area, but I still battle to understand the `Routes` class.

Let's say my module has one controller, action and view, Home, Index, and Index, being Home/Index. Once Orchard is up and running, how do I access this specific `Index` actin?

Comment: The same way you would any MVC action. Just don't forget to specify the area to be the folder name of the module.

Comment: The module folder is *Comair.RI*. It has a `HomeController` with an `Index` action and I have a `Home/Index` view. When I try the url `http://orchard-multi/Comair.RI/Home/Index` I get an Orchard 'Not found' error. There is no error log. I have no idea why what is not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good guide in the Orchard Documentation to [Creating an Orchard Module that uses its own controllers](http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Building-a-hello-world-module).

Here is a code sample taken from that guide that creates the routes for a module called HelloWorld:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Orchard.Mvc.Routes;

namespace HelloWorld {
    public class Routes : IRouteProvider {
        public void GetRoutes(ICollection<RouteDescriptor> routes) {
            foreach (var routeDescriptor in GetRoutes())
                routes.Add(routeDescriptor);
        }

        public IEnumerable<RouteDescriptor> GetRoutes() {
            return new[] {
                new RouteDescriptor {
                    Priority = 5,
                    Route = new Route(
                        "HelloWorld",
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "HelloWorld"},
                            {"controller", "Home"},
                            {"action", "Index"}
                        },
                        new RouteValueDictionary(),
                        new RouteValueDictionary {
                            {"area", "HelloWorld"}
                        },
                        new MvcRouteHandler())
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

If you create a class that implements IRouteProvider you can let Orchard know the routes for your controllers.

Comment: I assume `HelloWorld` is the name of the Module, and not just some arbitrary name picked for the route. The example I copied had a `null` in place of the second, empty `new RouteValueDictionary()`. Lets hope that was the fault.

Comment: The module is called HelloWorld. I've edited the answer to make that a bit clearer.